# Difference between "Random" and "Max Random" chaos modifier

Tags: djmax-respect-v

What's the difference in how the note charts are randomised when the different random options are selected? I.e. how is "max random" different from "random"?

Answer (score 1):

According to their Twitter post ([1](https://twitter.com/djmax_japan/status/1254683135930818562), [2](https://twitter.com/djmax_japan/status/1336930231181963265), [3](https://twitter.com/djmax_japan/status/1336965604931059712), it's all in Japanese):

The basic Random randomizes notes per note. In my experience, the randomized notes does not take into account the relationship between simultaneous presses and side notes, so it may be difficult to play on a gamepad (I'm using DJDAO's [EZMAX](https://www.dj-dao.com/en/ezmax) so...).

Half-Random randomizes notes per lane. Sidetrack and 8key L/R triggers are not subject to randomization. For example,

- 4B, 6B, 8B: Random placement in the left and right lanes.
- 5B: The center lane is fixed and the left and right two lanes are randomized.

Lastly, Max Random will place each note to a random lane. According to their tweet, it'll be adjusted so that the notes are not unevenly distributed in the same lane, so when compared to Random, I think this one is easier to play even with a gamepad.

Comment: Did you mean to say that the basic random randomises the lanes? If it randomises "note per note", then I still don't understand how that is different from your description of max random which places "each note to a random lane"

Comment: @Flaw No, literally randomizes notes per every note, but it doesn't have any algorhythm like Max Random has. But honestly, I also can't catch what's the difference between them...

Answer (score 1):

The basic "Random" randomizes every track's lane position, it basically permutates every lane number. On 5K, might give a challenge if the original charts have jacks on the center (3) track, both for keyboard and gamepad players. For gamepad players, 6K & 8K might give challenging/impossible patterns (e.g. 123 or 456 simultaneous notes, additional notes on the same side track). Example:

- 4K: [1234][SʟSʀ] → 4123|SʟSʀ
- 5K: [12345][SʟSʀ] → 35142|SʀSʟ
- 6K: [123456][SʟSʀ] → 216435|SʟSʀ
- 8K: [123456][(SʟL)(SʀR)] → 165324|SʀRSʟL (respective L/R lane follows side track lane to prevent clash for simultaneous L/R & side track long notes)

The "Half Random" also randomizes the track's lane position but is restricted to left and right lanes (thus, side tracks and L/R tracks are not affected). Should be still possible for gamepad players, but challenging patterns might still occur (i.e. 13 or 46 simultaneous notes on 6K/8K). Example:

- 4K: [12][34] → 2134|SʟSʀ
- 5K: [12][3][45] → 21354|SʟSʀ
- 6K: [123][456] → 312654|SʟSʀ
- 8K: [123][456] → 321456|SʟLSʀR

The "Max Random" randomizes each *note*'s lane position instead (on 8K, *L&R tracks are also included*), except for side tracks which are only randomized per lane (similar to the basic "Random"). Expect to see jacks (consecutive notes on the same lane) even though DJ Max claimed they tried to reduce the probability of it happening. Example on 8K:

- Original: 1 1 2 2 5 5 6 6
- Random: 5 5 2 2 3 3 1 1 (1→5, 2→2, 5→3, 6→1)
- Half Random: 2 2 1 1 5 5 4 4 (1→2, 2→1, 5→5, 6→4)
- Max Random:  2 L 6 6 R 3 5 1 (no fixed pattern)